# Unusable "Delete" action in the Suggested Edits review queue for a tag wiki excerpt

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

A few days ago I [reviewed a suggested edit to a tag wiki excerpt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/182841), and I noticed that there was a "Delete" option:

[image]

That seemed the best option to me since the tag was useless and needed to be deleted. However, clicking the "Submit" button with the "Delete" option selected did nothing. I ended up rejecting the edit, then removing the tag from the post it was on.

I suspect this option is intended for deleting a very low quality *post* (the text under the "Delete" option uses that word) but that's not really how you get rid of a tag -- and it seems that the review queue's logic conflates the two and presents an unusable option to delete.

In case it matters, I am a moderator for the site on which this suggested edit was made.

Comment: That Delete option does indeed only show for moderators, and AFAIK it deletes the post (not just the edit, one does not simply delete a suggested edit). And I agree, it does not make sense here.

Comment: If only it's possible to delete the entire tag by (ab)using the suggested edit...